# data binding in windows 8 metro style app using json data (c#)

Tags: c#, json, data-binding, windows-8, deserialization

I am trying to make an app in Visual Studio Express 2012 RC. I downloaded some JSON data and deserialized it. But after binding the data to a list box, instead of showing the actual content, it is showing `project-name.page-name+Datum` in text blocks.

**Here is the part of the XAML code:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="687" Margin="10,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1346" ItemsSource="{Binding data}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textblock1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="50" Width="443" Text="{Binding name}" />
</ListBox>
```

**Here is the part of xaml.cs code**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }

}
public class Datum
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**This is the code which I am using to de-serialize JSON data**

```
stream loading = await load.GetStreamAsync(....);
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
RootObject loaded = (RootObject) ser.ReadObject(loading);
listbox1.DataContext = loaded;
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong my the code? I am using the same thing in a Windows phone app and in that it is working fine except that I used webclient in it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added a UIElement to the ListBox's `Items` collection.  The proper way to get the item to display what you want would be to apply an ItemTemplate.  You can do it inline or reference a resource.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding data}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate
</ListBox>
```

It should work with that setup, though I have no tested it. If this worked, remember to mark it as the answer so others may learn from your inquiry.

*Side notes*

I'd also suggest scrubbing your sample code of any non-essential properties, for what it's worth. And avoid hard-coded width/margin values -- allow the application elements to size themselves proportionally.

Comment: thanks and as far as the side note is concerned i am just testing my app once it works i will redesign it......i do not know much about xaml can you tell me why it will not work using my method? i mean i am just adding a listbox and then a textblock from controls so everything is automatic?....i am going to try your method now

Comment: @user1489610 When you add a TextBlock inside the ListBox it thinks you want to add it to the item collection, but you've already set an ItemsSource, so those two are going to conflict.  The main issue with what you're seeing is that it *is* displaying the item, but it's displaying the item type because you don't have an `ItemTemplate` set up. If you define one like I have shown you, it will display the item as whatever you define. You can even set up a complex panel with multiple TextBlocks, Images, rectangles -- whatever you'd like.

Comment: yes your method is working perfectly fine...but still i want to know why not my method worked and how do i come to know that i have to add item template and data template in the code.....i am learner and trying to learn how things work and how i can reach to a solution myself...so any help will work....thanks again

Comment: Your best resource is to read the MSDN Reference Library.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) exactly explains why you saw what you did.